# Printing lines with similar text together

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sort

I am currently working on analyzing the performance of an application. I've starting by looking at the logs generated by our application and identifying the business logic tasks that are taking more than acceptable time to execute.

A snippet from the log file looks something like :

```
2014-07-02 18:03:20,269 INFO  [ROOT] - Task1. xmlRecord Id :35165 processed
2014-07-02 18:05:20,269 INFO  [ROOT] - Task1. xmlRecord Id :35162 processed
2014-07-02 18:15:20,269 INFO  [ROOT] - Task1. xmlRecord Id :35164 processed
2014-07-02 18:20:20,269 INFO  [ROOT] - Task2. xmlRecord Id :35165 processed
```

My requirement is to find the total amount of time spent on executing each task. For instance, the amount of time spent on Task2 for xmlRecord 35165 = End time for Task 2 for xmlRecord 35165 - End Time for Task 1 for xmlRecord 35165.

For this reason, I want a way to group all the log statements that have the same xmlRecord Id to be grouped together as shown below :

```
2014-07-02 18:03:20,269 INFO  [ROOT] - Task1. xmlRecord Id :35165 processed
2014-07-02 18:20:20,269 INFO  [ROOT] - Task2. xmlRecord Id :35165 processed
2014-07-02 18:05:20,269 INFO  [ROOT] - Task1. xmlRecord Id :35162 processed
2014-07-02 18:15:20,269 INFO  [ROOT] - Task1. xmlRecord Id :35164 processed
```

If I can group all the log statements as shown above, I will quickly be able to see that it took Task2 17 minutes to process xmlRecord 35165.

Note that the logs that I have shown here are not the exact logs that my application prints but just a sample. I want to be able to group all log statements such that logs for a particular XML id are always one after another.

I'm a bit rusty with the shell and would appreciate it if someone can point me to a one liner or a script that already does this so I don't waste time reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 5):

As a starter, why not sort on the `xmlRecord Id` column? :-

```
sort -k 9 -o <out.log> <in.log>
```

That should group them together in numerical order.  If you want to sort by `Task` too, then it will probably involve an `awk` script or similar.

#### How this works

The `sort` command can sort data in a variety of ways, in this case we're sorting it based on the value in the 9th column. It will use a standard alphanumeric sort unless otherwise directed.

```
.... -k 9 ....
```

The other arguments in the example are just to specify what input file to use (your log file) and a new file to output the results to, `-o <out.log>`.

Comment: I don't need the Task at the moment. The xmlRecord id should be sufficient for now. The example that I gave in my question is just a sample. If it is not too much to ask for, can you explain the one liner so I can tweak it the way I want and other community members can find this answer to be useful for them as well.

Comment: @slm - Thanks! You just beat me to it with the "How this works"

Comment: @garethTheRed - feel free to change it, was just helping the OP out 8-)

Answer (score 2):

If you have enough memory to load the whole file, try:

```
$ perl -ane '
    push @h, [$F[1],(split(/:/,$F[8]))[1],$_];
    END {
        print map { $_->[2] }
              sort { $b->[1] <=> $a->[1]
                     ||
                     $a->[0] cmp $b->[0]
                   }
              @h;
    }
' file
2014-07-02 18:03:20,269 INFO  [ROOT] - Task1. xmlRecord Id :35165 processed
2014-07-02 18:20:20,269 INFO  [ROOT] - Task2. xmlRecord Id :35165 processed
2014-07-02 18:15:20,269 INFO  [ROOT] - Task1. xmlRecord Id :35164 processed
2014-07-02 18:05:20,269 INFO  [ROOT] - Task1. xmlRecord Id :35162 processed
```

**Explanation**

- While processing the file, we create an array `@h`, each of its elements is an array ref. Each array ref contains three element:

  - The time appears in log file, like `18:03:20,269`
  - The XML record ID
  - The whole log entry
- Final, we print the result with the condition:

  - sort by XML record ID first `$b->[1] <=> $a->[1]`, reversely
  - If ID is equal, we compare by the time appear in log `$a->[0] cmp $b->[0]`

Comment: I have enough memory to load the whole file but the example that I gave in my question is just a sample. If it is not too much to ask for, can you explain the script so I can tweak it the way I want and other community members can find this answer to be useful for them as well.